# Can I call java applet from Matlab code

Tags: java, matlab, applet, processing

I want to call Java applet (specifically processing sketch) from inside Matlab code, can I do it and if so how, are there any examples.

Answer (score 1):

Applet? Probably not, but Matlab has it's own JVM, so anything you can run from a "java ..." command line, you can run from Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to read that:
[the link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/07/06/calling-java-from-matlab/?doing_wp_cron)

MATLAB Spoken Here
July 6th, 2009
Calling Java from MATLAB

So far no one has taken me up on the extra credit from the Interactive Web Pages post. I thought the problem of displaying a figure without an image file was too interesting to pass up, so I figured out the solution myself and put it up on the file exchange. The second challenge involving ActiveX will remain open until I get chance to write up its solution. Or, if you don't have the time to do that, you can still win a t-shirt by sending us your desktop.
...